# C# to pass class type to base constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Well, this is a <del>convoluted</del>/complicated question, and here it goes:

- I have two pair of classes

  - `Derived` class inherits from the `Base` class (`class Derived: Base{}`)
  - `Class2` inherits from `Class1` (`class Class2: Class1 {}`)

My current `Class1` constructor has:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
```

What I want is that the type `Derived` is passed from the `Class2` constructor into its base (`Class1`) constructor. Is that possible?

More complete code:

```
class Base   
{  
    public Base() {  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Base Constructor");  
    }
    ~Base() {  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Base Destructor");  
    }  
}  

class Derived1: Base {  
    public Derived1() {  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside The Derived1 Constructor");  
    }
    ~Derived1() {  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside The Derived1 Destructor");  
    }  
}

class Derived2: Base {  
    public Derived2() {  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside The Derived2 Constructor");  
    }
    ~Derived2() {  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside The Derived2 Destructor");  
    }  
}

class Class1  
{  
    protected int a, b;  
    public Class1() {  
        a = 0;  
        b = 0;  
        Derived1 obj=new Derived1();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside base class default constructor");  
    }  
    public Class1(int a, int b, Derived1) {  
        this.a = a;  
        this.b = b;  
        Derived1 obj=new Derived1();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside base class parameterized constructor");  
    }  
}  
class Class2: Class1 {  
    int c;  
    public Class2(int a, int b, int c): base(a, b, Derived1) {  
        this.c = c;  
        Console.WriteLine("Inside derived class parametrized constructor");  
    }  
}
```

I.e., by `base(a, b, Derived1)` I want to pass from `Class2` constructor/definition, what type `Class1` will new, whether it is `Derived1` or `Derived2`.

Hope that I've made this <del>convoluted</del>/complicated question clear.

Comment: 'Type' type argument and typeof in caller?

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly. But to me it looks like Since the expected parameter type is `Derived1` in the constructor of both `Class1` and `Class2` it will be always `Derived1` object available to them. `Derived2` class is different from `Derived1` so you can not actually use it in place of `Derived1` in `Class1` and `Class2` constuctors.

Comment: what do you mean by "what type Class1 will new, whether it is Derived1 or Derived2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `typeof` keyword used below:

```
class Class2 : Class1
{
    int c;
    public Class2(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b, typeof(Derived1))
    {
        this.c = c;
        Console.WriteLine("Inside derived class parametrized constructor");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Class2 c2 = new Class2(1,2, 3);
}
```

Or write more generic form using [C# generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) like this:

```
class Class1<T> where T: new()
{
    protected int a, b;
    public Class1()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        T obj = new T();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside base class parameterized constructor, with {0}", typeof (T));
    }

    public Class1(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        T obj = new T();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside base class parameterized constructor");
    }
}

class Class2<T> : Class1<T> where T: new()
{
    int c;
    public Class2(int a, int b, int c) : base(a, b)
    {
        this.c = c;
        Console.WriteLine("Inside derived class parametrized constructor");
    }
}


void Main()
{
    var c2 = new Class2<Derived1>(1, 2, 3);
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
    var c2_2 = new Class2<Derived2>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

And the output will be:

```
Inside Base Constructor
Inside The Derived1 Constructor
Inside base class parameterized constructor, with Derived1
Inside derived class parametrized constructor
-----
Inside Base Constructor
Inside The Derived2 Constructor
Inside base class parameterized constructor, with Derived2
Inside derived class parametrized constructor
```

I hope this help.